# How to make a image look more uniform without losing fine details

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a reconstructed object with accumulated effects of lighting as shown below, which looks quite dirty:

[image: A dirty image]

I want to make the body of the object to have a more uniform color
(cleaner) while keeping the fine details of letters, patterns, etc.

What I am current doing is to fit the image in HSV space while down weighting the S and V channel( so hopefully same color with different brightness and saturation belongs to the same cluster) with fixed number of GMM components and use the mean for each pixel. The result of course lose all the fine details:

[image: After GMM]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for a edge-preserving smoothing. Look for example for the bilateral filter. -- Funny note: the bilateral filter was published independently 3 times, in one of those papers it's called "SUSAN", thought you might like that. :)

Comment: k-means clustering?

Answer (score 4):

A mixture model is clever, but IMO overkill; it's assigning the "most likely" pixel value based on a model that has very few good statistical properties.

I think traditional computer vision is your friend here for repeatability and ease of implementation: rank filters are one possibility, and they're well established in the standard python scientific stack (*)

- [Here are the skimage rank filters](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html)
- [For completion, many more skimage filters that might be helpful](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html)

For example, on your image, some of the most common filters at a kernel size of 3 in the top row and 10 in the bottom row look like:

[image]

The titles are a little hard to read if you don't click on the image; that's, from left to right, [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter), [mean](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/mean.htm), [bilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter), [contrast](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#skimage.filters.rank.enhance_contrast), and [percentile](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/r.vandenboomgaard/IPCV20172018/LectureNotes/IP/LocalOperators/percentilefilter.html).

My instinct was a median filter, but clearly you have options

Comment: @CrisLuengo ya that link was pretty bad, thanks for actually clicking through them :) Changed it to just be the skimage description, which is terse but has a brief description and a link to a source implementation at least. I'll find something independent and swap it out

Comment: Ah, now I know what operation you're applying! :) I know it as "morphological toggle operator". Here's a figure I found: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/llustrates-a-one-dimensional-example-of-the-toggle-contrast-operator_fig5_29600691 It's not easy to find a formal description...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Idon't think I phrased my question very well... I am trying to make the background color of the box( in this example, white and yellow) to be a uniform color without the brighter and darker regions while still keeping the texts and logos clear. I don't think a simple filter will be the solution, as shown in the results the dark, uniform color still exists on all the filtered images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CLAHE? It is a version of local contrast normalisation. The local nature of it helps balance out contrast across the image. For color images it works in HSV space. It works best on natural scenes though so for this a bilateral filter as mentioned by Cris Luengo may work best.

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist